# Relation between 'This' Pointer and Vtable Functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, managed-c++

I do not have much idea about the functionality of the Virtual Table, but in the code pasted below - the `this` pointer passed is obviously points to different locations in the 2 cases - but the function `show()` in the memory - is it instantiated/meaning created separately for every object at Runtime? (Forgive my poor understanding of C++ jargons)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
      int x;
      public:
            A(){x=0;}
            A(int z){x=z;}
            void show()
            {  
                 if(x==0)
                 cout<<"\nCalled by OBJ_1";
                 else
                 cout << "\nCalled by OBJ_2";
            }
};

int main()
{
 A OBJ_1,OBJ_2(1);
 OBJ_1.show();
 OBJ_2.show();
}
```

If an example (with some memory-diagrams if possible) could be provided regarding how the Virtual Table works and the functionality of the `this` pointer w.r.t Virtual Table could be explained, i would much appreciate it.

Comment: Remember vtables are an implementation detail, and not guaranteed to be there by the standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A` does not have a vtable at all (or it shouldn't on any good compiler) because it is not a polymorphic class:  it has no virtual member functions.

The function `show()` exists in the executable exactly once.  Member functions aren't really different from ordinary nonmember functions, they just have an extra, implicit `this` parameter.  You can think of it as if the compiler transforms a member function into a similar nonmember function, for example:

```
void show(A* this)
{
    if (this->x == 0)
        cout << "\nCalled by OBJ_1";
    else    
        cout << "\nCalled by OBJ_2";  
}
```

Instead of `OBJ_1.show()`, the comparable way to call this nonmember function would be to use `show(&OBJ_1)`.

There isn't one `A::show()` per `A` object that is created.  There's one `A::show()` total and it takes as an argument the instance on which it was called.

Comment: Leaving aside the Vtable thing, what about the show() function?

Comment: But how can we do this --this->x with the help of non-member function show(&OBJ_1) -- when x is private??I wont be able to access wont i??

Comment: @Acme:  If _you_ write a nonmember function `void show(A*)` like this, then no, you wouldn't be able to write `this->x`.  However, you can think of the transformation from `void A::show()` to `void show(A*)` as how _the compiler_ implements a member function.

Answer (score 1):

C++ standard doesn't define the term "virtual table" explicitly. An implementation is free to implement a polymorphic class (a class which has at least one virtual function) in any way it wants. But most common implementations use a v-table with  v-ptr.

Check out what [Marshall Cline has to say about virtual functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.3)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is only one copy of the code corresponding to each function (member or non-member). The function uses the `this` pointer to determine which object to actually operate on.

You don't have any `virtual` methods so there's no vtable in your code at all.